# Use lookup table with variable number of query strings to find lookup value in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two sheets that have the same columns. One has a bunch of "input" data, and the other has a bunch of lookup data.

## Input Table

| one | two | three | four | five |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| alpha | 1 | bravo | TRUE | ??? |
| bravo | 2 | charlie | FALSE | ??? |
| alpha | 3 | charlie | FALSE | ??? |
| delta | 1 | bingo | TRUE | ??? |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| random | 4 | random | FALSE | ??? |

## Lookup Table

| one | two | three | four | five |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| alpha |  |  |  | yes |
|  | 2 |  | false | no |
| delta | 1 |  |  | maybe |

- In `Input Table`, column `five` is what I want to populate
- In `Lookup Table`, column `five` has the value I want to lookup based on matches from the other columns

The idea is that each row in `Lookup Table` has criteria to look for in `Input Table` and if a row matches, pull the value `Lookup Tabele`.`five` into `Input Table`.`five`.

Using my example above, the output would look like:

| one | two | three | four | five |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| alpha | 1 | bravo | TRUE | yes (cause alpha matches the first row in `Lookup Table`) |
| bravo | 2 | charlie | FALSE | no (cause 2 and false match the coresponding rows in `Lookup Table`) |
| alpha | 3 | charlie | FALSE |  |
| delta | 1 | bingo | TRUE | maybe |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| random | 4 | random | FALSE |  |

I'm not sure how to do this multiple lookups?

My real data has 100 columns.

Answer (score 0):

*Here's one approach you may test out:*

```js
=index(let(Σ,sequence(1,4),Λ,int(mod(sequence(2^columns(Σ))/2^sequence(1,columns(Σ),0),2)),
       iferror(+tocol(xlookup(byrow(chooserows(Λ,sequence(rows(Λ)-1)),lambda(x,join(,switch(x,1,A2:D2,0,"Δ")))),byrow(I:L,lambda(y,join(,switch(y,"","Δ",y)))),M:M,),3),"-")))
```

[image]

- *Unsure how it would fare with 100 columns thing!*
- *did not make it array-style formula as the backend heavy calculations might result in **lambda** `calculation-limit-reached` error*

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, using a truth table and filtering. As with the previous answer, I don't know how well this will work on 100 columns. `inputRng` is your input table, `lookupRng` is the first four columns of your lookup table and `resultRng` is the last column. These ranges do not include the header of your tables:

```
=ArrayFormula(let(
inputRng,A1:D5,
lookupRng,H1:K3,
resultRng,L1:L3,
byrow(inputRng,lambda(inputRow,let(
   truthTbl_,if(len(lookupRng),inputRow=lookupRng,true),
   ifna(filter(resultRng,byrow(truthTbl_,lambda(truthRow,and(truthRow))))))))))
```